# Production Docker container hosting React shuts down

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

My dockerized react app is ready for deployment but shuts down after 10 or so seconds in the production environment. I have `restart: unless-stopped` in the `docker-compose.prod.yml` file which makes it restart every 10 or so seconds.

I have tried adding `std_in: true` and `tty: true` to the `docker-compose.prod.yml` file, as suggested, to no avail.

**Docker Compose**:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${BACKEND_IMAGE}"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/backend/static
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db

  # redis:
  #   image: redis:alpine
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   depends_on:
  #     - backend

  # celery:
  #   build:
  #     context: ./backend
  #   image: "${BACKEND_IMAGE}"
  #   command: celery -A backend worker -l info
  #   env_file: .env
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   depends_on:
  #     - redis

  # celery-beat:
  #   build:
  #     context: ./backend
  #   image: "${BACKEND_IMAGE}"
  #   command: celery -A backend beat -l info
  #   env_file: .env
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   depends_on:
  #     - redis

  frontend:
    image: "${FRONTEND_IMAGE}"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - frontend_build:/frontend/build
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - backend
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - frontend_build:/var/www/frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
      - db
    command: '/bin/sh -c ''while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'''

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

volumes:
  frontend_build:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

**Dockerfile.prod**:

```
FROM node:16.13.0

# Create and set the working directory on the container
# then copy over the package.json and package-lock.json
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the node packages before copying the files
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# Run the production build
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

**`docker logs [frontend_container]`**:

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> frontend@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
```

Thoughts on how to fix the issue? Could this be a permissions issue?

**EDIT**: I am serving with Nginx in a docker container:

```
upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location /api/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    
    location /static/ {      
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    root /var/www/frontend;
    server_name example.co www.example.co;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exmplae.co/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }

    location /static/ {      
        alias /backend/static/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the logs saying?

Comment: the way you show it here, you are not using nginx to serve it. You literally try to run the container which does a build. It is expected that it shuts down after build.

Comment: Updated to show full `docker-compose` file

Comment: I am not really getting your setup. Why are you using the backend image for the frontend as well? How do you populate the frontend volume? Why do you have a *frontend* and nginx? Why are you not adding the statics directly into the nginx image?

Comment: I am not using a backend image for my frontend. The are separate images.. I have different containers for different services..

Comment: right, I didnt see those are 2 variables. But you show us here in your question your Dockerfile.prod which is used on the backend. And It's still the question of why do you have a frontend AND nginx. Nginx is literally the file server for the statics. Also how do you populate the frontend volume. And what is the log output.

Comment: I see. I am coming from backend development where I need to run migrations, etc so it makes sense to have it separate. It feels weird to have the frontend and nginx as one container but I guess it makes sense as there is only static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have build your app, you should serve your app with a webserver like nginx. So, in your dockerfile add these lines to use an nginx docker image, copy your build into into and run it to the port 80.

```
FROM node:16.13.0

# Create and set the working directory on the container
# then copy over the package.json and package-lock.json
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the node packages before copying the files
RUN npm install


# install react-scripts if needed
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . .

# build your app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.17.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# change the left path with yours, below the file content
COPY src/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the nginx.conf:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am serving with Nginx. That is not the issue. The issue is that the React docker container will not stay running. It restarts every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: If the Nginx container is only serving static files and not proxying to a backend, you don't need a custom configuration; just copying the static files into `/usr/share/nginx/html` is enough.  You also don't need to repeat the `EXPOSE` or `CMD` directives that come from the `nginx` base image.

Comment: @DavidAlford As you've written your current Dockerfile, the container runs `npm run build` and then exits.  So the essence of this answer is, you need something to actually serve the built files; `RUN npm run build` at image build time and then `COPY` the files to something that will serve them in a multi-stage build.

Comment: Bare with me as I am a little confused. The site shows up for 10 or so seconds then the container shuts down. I add the full `docker-compose` .

Comment: @DavidMaze how can I keep the `frontend` container running?

Comment: Do what this answer suggests.  Delete `frontend` as a container in the `docker-compose.yml` and copy the results of its build into the Nginx proxy.

Comment: @DavidMaze `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` this is required for SPA kind of apps. So just copying the statics isnt enough.

Comment: @DavidMaze I submitted an answer with updates to this, with the goal of what I was trying to accomplish (a CI/CD pipeline)..

Answer (score 1):

So, the other answers are correct. The way I had it setup, the `npm run build` command is run, then the container exits. Also, as the other answers are correct, a multi-stage build seems to work best here for the production image - though I made some adjustments, for a better CI/CD pipeline, that I would like to share.

First, I do not like merging my `frontend` build and my `nginx` build as these are separate services. Nginx interacts with not only the frontend, but the backend as well and I would like to run frontend tests on my React code before building the `nginx` image. Therefore I separated the `frontend` image and the `nginx` image to help in my CI/CD pipeline.

Here is my project tree structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile.prod
├── backend
├── data
├── docker-compose.ci.yml
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend
├── init-letsencrypt.sh
├── nginx
└── .github
```

First, I build a `frontend` image using a `Dockerfile.ci` file which runs tests using the `CMD` option - the `CMD` option is important here as it will be overridden if you pass another `CMD` in a `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` file (which we will do later on):

```
FROM node:16.13.0

# Create and set the working directory on the container
# then copy over the package.json and package-lock.json
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the node packages before copying the files
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# Run the development server
CMD ["npm", "run", "test"]
```

My GitHub Actions workflow runs the `frontend` build on push to the repo. If tests fail, it won't get to the next step - building the `nginx` image. If tests pass, it will push the image to GitHub container registry and build the `nginx` image.

The `nginx` image uses the `frontend` image as a `build` image:

```
# Here we use the image which was pushed to the registry
FROM ghcr.io/digibrainllc/digibrain-advertising-api/frontend:latest as build

# Then we create production build by **overriding** the previous `CMD` statment
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]

# Production environment
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

COPY --from=build /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /nginx/conf/nginx.prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

This way the `docker-compose.ci`, which is used for building images and running tests, looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${BACKEND_IMAGE}"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - media_volume:/backend/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ci
    image: "${FRONTEND_IMAGE}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    stdin_open: true
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - static_volume:/backend/static
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - db
    # Could also put a `CMD` here which would run last in the `nginx` image build

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

This keeps a separation between the services! Hope someone finds this useful!